# Watch for variable change

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh, centos

I'm trying to log all commands that users run on our servers and then ship them into one centralized logging server.

For that, I created an rsyslog logger that writes everything into one file (`/var/log/commands.log`) using the `history` command. I then use filebeat to ship the logs to the log-server. My problem is someone being able to `unset HISTFILE` which would stop logging. I'm not too worried about someone doing `echo "" > .bash_history` because I'm shipping logs immediately to another server.

It shouldn't be super fool-proof because everything can be outsmarted, but I would still like to improve it. Is it possible to create an audit watch for changes to `HISTFILE`? Or create some sort of listener that whenever a user unsets HISTFILE it would immediately set it back & alert me? Should I create some daemon that sets HISTFILE every 5 seconds?

Huge thanks ahead!

Just as a side note, I know it's possible to log commands with auditd but it recorded commands that the system runs too which cluttered everything.

Comment: Thanks for the response, would it prevent users from doing `unset HISTFILE`?

Comment: I need all users to be unable to `unset HISTFILE`, or, be able to know when someone runs `unset HISTFILE`

Comment: HISTFILE is an environment variable, it just point to ~.bash_history. how do I set readonly for a variable?

Comment: Solved, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solved,

Created a file: `/etc/profile.d/histfile.sh`

and in it put :

```
HISTFILE="${HOME:-~}/.bash_history"
readonly HISTFILE
```